# Remove last matching value from a list in Python

Tags: python, algorithm

Let's say I have a list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5]`. Since `2` occurs twice, I want to remove the last occurrence of two. This is what I have done so far.

```
list.reverse()
list.remove(value) # value = 2
list.reverse()
```

But it seems that if I'm doing reversing twice for deleting a value, the algorithm complexity would be `O(n)`. Is there any faster way of doing it?

Comment: I don't know Python but probably this may answer your question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists

Comment: Because we must check every value in the list to find the duplicate, there is no faster way than `O(n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if value in list:
    list.reverse()
    list.remove('ch')
    list.reverse()
```

The most pythonic way would be to do a `try: except` around remove:

```
list.reverse()
try:
    list.remove(value)
except:
    pass
list.reverse()
```

As per your comment on speed, both of these methods are O(N), as `x in list` and `list.reverse()` are both O(N), so there's not much between them. If you expect the element to usually be there, you can save the `x in list` check by using try: catch, however if you expect it to usually not be there, you can save the 2 `reverse()`s by checking for membership first.

Comment: You are ignoring an exception. Use `try ... finally ...` instead. Or, better, don’t modify the list before removing the item.

Comment: I won’t recommend this answer. It has two pitfalls: it redefines the builtin `list` function (really bad) and mask an exception (also bad).

Answer (score 1):

This approach removes one of the reversals at least:

```
def rremove(alist, x):
    alist.pop(len(alist) - alist[::-1].index(x) - 1)

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5]

print(my_list)

rremove(my_list, 2)

print(my_list)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Just like `list.remove()`, it raises ValueError if the value is not present.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dict , since dict can have unique values :

```
values=[1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5]


no_repeat ={}
for i,j in enumerate(values):
    if j not in no_repeat:
        no_repeat[i]=j
    else:
        pass

print(no_repeat.values())
```

output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the most efficient would be by iterating the list in reverse order, find the value 2, delete it and break the loop:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 5]

for index, item in enumerate(reversed(l)):
    if item == 2:
        l.pop(len(l) - 1 - index)
        break
```

You get:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

That way you don’t copy the list in memory nor loop twice.

Comment: @cdlane It does not. `reversed` returns a reverse iterator.  `l[::-1]` creates a new list.

Comment: @DylanYoung, I agree on this key difference but I think we're looking at two different efficiencies.  This is more *space* efficient, as you note, but I'm guessing it's less *time* efficient as it uses a Python loop to walk an iterator instead of a **C** loop to walk a list.  Maybe a close call given the time taken to copy the list.

Comment: @cdlane Absolutely.  Nothing wrong with either solution, just different :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler function to remove an element's last occurrence in a list if found:

```
def right_remove(l: list, element: Any) -> None:
    try:
        index = l[::-1].index(element)
    except ValueError:
        return
    
    l.pop(len(l) - index - 1)
```